# Allocating a fixed character array vs. a pointer for casting to string

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new to C, and trying to understand why the following works with a fixed-size character array but not with a pointer:

```
float number = 1245.12;

// allocate a character array for the buffer
char number_as_string[50];
sprintf(number_as_string, "%f", number);
```

But allocating a pointer (which I thought would point to a location in memory, and allow iterating to the next memory point, etc.) would not work:

```
float number = 1245.12;

// allocate a pointer
char * number_as_string;
sprintf(number_as_string, "%f", number);
```

Comment: You didn't "allocate a pointer" -- you declared a pointer variable, but you didn't allocate any memory for it to point to.

Comment: `char number_as_string[50];
sprintf(number_as_string, "%f", number);` will also fail for `number = -DBL_MAX`.  I suspect you need `char number_as_string[DBL_MAX_10_EXP + 10];` or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer your question in two parts.

You wrote

```
float number = 1245.12;
char number_as_string[50];
sprintf(number_as_string, "%f", number);
```

That's fine and will work, although of course one problem with fixed-size buffers like these is that it's easy to overflow them, sometimes with catastrophic results.  So a preferred alternative is

```
snprintf(number_as_string, sizeof(number_as_string), "%f", number);
```

`snprintf` is a variant of `sprintf` that lets you specify the size of the buffer.  That way, `snprintf` can take care not to write more characters to the buffer than it will hold.

So now let's see about using `snprintf` with your second example:

```
char *number_as_string;
snprintf(number_as_string, ???, "%f", number);
```

But what size do we use?  How big is the buffer pointed to by this second `number_as_string`?  We don't know, and this helps us realize that we haven't yet allocated a buffer for the second `number_as_string` to point to at all.

What you want to do is use `malloc` to allocate some memory for `number_as_string` to point to:

```
number_as_string = malloc(50);
```

Now, and assuming `malloc` succeeds, you know what number to hand to `snprintf` as the buffer size:

```
snprintf(number_as_string, 50, "%f", number);
```

Realistically, of course, we'd have a variable holding the allocated buffer size, rather than repeating the number "50" in multiple places.  So here's the more realistic example, including the test to make sure `malloc` didn't fail:

```
int buffer_size = 50;
char *number_as_string = malloc(buffer_size);
if(number_as_string == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(1);
}
snprintf(number_as_string, buffer_size, "%f", number);
```

Just make sure you don't do:

```
snprintf(number_as_string, sizeof(number_as_string), "%f", number);
```

when `number_as_string` is a pointer.  In that case, you'll get the size of the pointer (typically 4 or 8 bytes, these days), *not* the size of the pointed-to buffer, which is what you want.

I like to understand memory allocation, and pointers, with little box-and-arrow diagrams.  Here's `char number_as_string[50]`:

```
                  +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+   +--+--+
number_as_string: |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |...|  |  |
                  +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+   +--+--+
```

Here's `char *number_as_string` followed by a successful `number_as_string = malloc(50)`:

```
                  +-------+
number_as_string: |   *   |
                  +---|---+
                      |
                      v
                     +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+   +--+--+
                     |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |...|  |  |
                     +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+   +--+--+
```

But here's `char *number_as_string` all by itself:

```
                  +-------+
number_as_string: |   *--------> ???
                  +-------+
```

The arrow -- the pointer -- points "nowhere".

Comment: thanks so much, this is really helpful to understanding things. Cheers for the answer (hopefully it's helpful to other beginners as well).

Comment: If `number_as_string` is a global pointer (which would mean that it's zero-initialized), then it should point to `8)X` (my terrible impression of a skull-and-crossbones).

Comment: @JL2210 Who needs ASCII art when we've got Unicode? →☠

Comment: Yeah. Let's just edit that in in the place of the last `???`, and replace "nowhere" with "to death".

Answer (score 2):

A pointer variable needs something to point to, and in your second example `number_as_string` doesn't point to anything.  Attempting to dereference it via a call to `sprintf` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to either allocate space dynamically:

```
char * number_as_string = malloc(50);
```

Or make it point someplace valid:

```
char str[50];
char * number_as_string = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case

```
char number_as_string[50];
sprintf(number_as_string, "%f", 123.456);
```

you have an automatic-storage variable that is an array of 50 `char`s. This array is usualy on the stack, so when you call `sprintf()`, you are "printing" on valid memory.

In the second case

```
char * number_as_string;
sprintf(number_as_string, "%f", 123.456);
```

you also have an automatic variable. However this variable is only a pointer. You did not ask the compiler for an array. Furthermore, you didn't initialize the pointer, so you cannot even tell whether `sprintf()` will even receive a memory location that belongs to your program.

This is what you are looking for:

```
char * number_as_string = malloc(50);
sprintf(number_as_string, "%f", 123.456);
```